# Monotonic coloring of the directed graph in python

Tags: python, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have been working on the implementation of the directed graph monotonic coloring algorithm. This implies the following specifications: The number of colors should be a minimum, the number of color for the node from which the edge starts must be smaller than the color of the node where it ends (for example: 1 -> 3, 3 -> 10). There are no cycles in the data if that helps. As an input we have two dictionaries: {node number: {nodes that connect to it}, ... } and {node number: {nodes that it connects to}, ...}.

The result of the program is the minimal number of colors needed.

I have the code which seems to be working, but I can't tell if it actually finds the minimum, and not just any suitable number. Here it is:

```
import numpy as np

def check(cols, curr):
  # this is basically the same thing as in the main function, but recursive.
  if curr in new:
    for i in new[curr]:
      if cols[i] >= cols[curr]:
        cols[i] = cols[curr] - 1
        cols = check(cols, i)

  if curr in new1:
    for i in new1[curr]:
      if cols[i] <= cols[curr]:
        cols[i] = cols[curr] + 1
        cols = check(cols, i)

  return cols

def get_ans():
  cols = [-1 for i in range(ndots)] 

  for g in range(ndots):
    print(g)
    print(cols)

    
    if g in new:
      to = [cols[_] for _ in new[g]] # color of nodes connected to this one
      toi = list(new[g])             # index of nodes connected to this one
    else: 
      to = set()
      toi = set()
    if g in new1:
      fr = [cols[_] for _ in new1[g]] # color of nodes this one is connected to
      fri = list(new1[g])             # index of nodes which this one connects to
    else: 
      fr = set()
      fri = set()
    print('near', toi, fri)

    for i in range(len(fr)):
      if cols[g] == -1:
        cols[g] = ndots
        cols[fri[i]] = ndots + 1
      elif cols[fri[i]] <= cols[g]: # if the coloring inconsistency is found
        cols[fri[i]] = cols[g] + 1
        cols = check(cols, fri[i])  # check if anything has to be changed

    for i in range(len(to)):
      if cols[g] == -1:
        cols[g] = ndots
        cols[toi[i]] = ndots - 1
      elif cols[toi[i]] >= cols[g]: # if the coloring inconsistency is found
        cols[toi[i]] = cols[g] - 1
        cols = check(cols, toi[i]) # check if anything has to be changed

    # print(cols)

  return len(np.unique(cols))


ndots = 8 # number nodes
new = {0: {1, 2}, 3: {1}, 5: {1, 4, 7}, 6: {2, 4}, 4: {0}, 2: {3}, 7: {3, 6}}  
new1 = new 
new = {}
for i in new1:
  for j in new1[i]:
    if j not in new: new[j] = set()
    new[j].add(i)

temp = new
new = new1
new1 = temp

print(new)  # first dictionary
print(new1) # second dictionary

print(get_ans())
```

Sorry for the mess above :). If you have a better idea of how to do this (the main thing I want is knowing that it will be the minimum), please help me with that, It will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a directed acyclic graph, thus there is a [topological order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in your nodes. If you process the nodes in this order, you are guaranteed that you always processed all ancestors of a node N before you process N itself.

Thus, simply going through them in this order and assigning

```
color[node] = max(color[ancestor] for ancestor in ancestors[node]) + 1
              or 0 if no ancestor exists
```

gives you a coloring that matches your requirements.

It will give the roots of the DAG the color 0. For all other nodes, this sets the color to the lowest legal value the node could possibly have. Since we process the nodes in the topological order, we can be sure that all ancestors always already have their correct values set.

Note: This algorithmic idea is usually used to find the length of the [longest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) to each node in your DAG. This means that your problem is the same as finding the length of the longest path, and your required color count is always the same as this length.

```py
def monotonic_coloring(adjacencies):
    inverse_adjacencies = [set() for _ in range(len(adjacencies))]
    for node, adjacent_nodes in enumerate(adjacencies):
        for child in adjacent_nodes:
            inverse_adjacencies[child].add(node)

    unprocessed_incoming_edge_count = [
        len(inverse_adjacencies[node]) for node in range(len(adjacencies))
    ]
    without_unprocessed_incoming_edge = {
        node
        for node in range(len(adjacencies))
        if unprocessed_incoming_edge_count[node] == 0
    }
    colors = [0 for _ in range(len(adjacencies))]

    while len(without_unprocessed_incoming_edge) != 0:
        node = without_unprocessed_incoming_edge.pop()
        colors[node] = max(
            (colors[ancestor] + 1 for ancestor in inverse_adjacencies[node]),
            default=0
        )
        for child in adjacencies[node]:
            unprocessed_incoming_edge_count[child] -= 1
            if unprocessed_incoming_edge_count[child] == 0:
                without_unprocessed_incoming_edge.add(child)

    return colors

coloring1 = monotonic_coloring([
    {1, 2}, set(), {3}, {1}, {0}, {1, 4, 7}, {2, 4}, {3, 6},
])
coloring2 = monotonic_coloring([
    {1}, {3}, {3}, {4, 5}, {6}, {6}, set(), {6}, {9}, set(),
])

print(coloring1)
print(coloring2)

import numpy as np
print(len(np.unique(coloring2)))
```

If I call your code with the second graph, I get output 6, where only 5 different colors are necessary. It seems that the main problem is the disconnected part of the graph (nodes 8 and 9). You can reproduce this with this input:

```
new = {0: {1}, 1: {3}, 2: {3}, 3: {4, 5}, 4: {6}, 5: {6}, 6: set(), 7: {6}, 8: {9}, 9: set()}
ndots = len(new)
```

The recursive approach of propagating changes through the graph can work, but it will have bad run time complexity because for bad input, you will have to propagate lots of changes through the same part of the graph again and again.